# Div compatibility problems in firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox, html, compatibility

I have created an asp.net site which works fine in internet explorer but for some reason some strange things are happening in firefox and safari.

I have some links in a div on the left, these work ok but you need to move the mouse around over them for a while before they highlight and are very intermittent, they are standard hyperlinks.

I have a couple of pages which have a maincontent div in the middle which contains an iframe, this iframe is pointed to another aspx page containing a datalist showing product categories, when i run the page like this, you can only click on something in the far right column (out of 3), if i open the datalist directly in FF it works ok.

I have a login link situated further down the page, this is within a div and works fine in IE but in FF it does absolutely nothing, the pointer does not change on hover and you cannot highligh the text.

I think this is the first time developing that i have actually appreciated internet explorer!

Comment: if your site is working ok in IE, then surely your code has errors :-P ....

Comment: Yeh and the annoying thing is that all the good developer tools are available within IE so i dont have much to help me in Firefox.

Comment: Again, you have amazed me....Firefox and safari have better tools to help out than IE....visit [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/?src=cb-dl-mostpopular)

Comment: Well what i meant was i already have the IE tools installed, i write web applications for IE intranet usually and this is my first asp.net website so i am not really geared up for browser testing but in all honesty i wasnt expecting so many issues.

Comment: On Web, I follow two simple tests. One is for internet browsers and other is for IE. The guys at microsoft always throw something weird when it comes to HTML and CSS standards.

Comment: Am i more likely to have a succesful result if i develop based on FF? Is it likely to work ok in IE?

Comment: If you are developing for the web, you should test for all the browsers but in general, you should take firefox or chrome as the benchmark, rather than the IE

Comment: Feel free to take a look at the site in firefox if you have it (www.customwebs.co.uk) you will soon see some problems. By the way i am away that on the home page things are walking around a bit, this is because i am mid way through messing around with the CSS to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Login" link does not work in firefox (or chrome) because its actually covered by the div with id "copyright" which is obviously not positioned correctly. (inspect it or give it a background-color and see) - this also partially obscures the left links which is why they appear "intermittent".

Comment: Is this whats happening on the products page for the 2 left hand side categories?

Comment: Yes it is - inspect it/colour it and you can see

Comment: Ok thanks, i will install firebug when i get home and have a look. Still strange how IE has no problem with it though isnt it, but i have suspected maybe a div positioning thing.

Comment: The div is still incorrectly positioned in IE, look at its border in its dev tools, IE however honours the click-through to the links

Comment: Oh yeah, just added Firebug lite for IE and i can see what its doing, very interesting tool.

Answer (score 1):

you can try firebug extension for firefox
best web developer tool i've used till now

Comment: Will this test compatibility issues? including ones where a dive might be overlapping another one somehow?

Comment: it will only test it on firefox (it's a ff extension after all), but you can see elements boundaries, style, javascript errors, etc ,.....